# Are monoidal categories equivalent to their categories of monoids via the forgetful functor necessarily cocartesian?

Tags: monoidal-categories

Given any category $C$ with finite coproducts (regarded as a cocartesian monoidal category), every object $X$ of $C$ is uniquely a monoid with the codiagonal map $\nabla:X+X \to X$ as the multiplication and the unique map $0 \to X$ as the unit. Also, every morphism in $C$ is a morphism of monoids.

> Conversely, if $C$ is a monoidal category for which the forgetful functor $\operatorname{Mon}(C) \to C$ is an equivalence (where $\operatorname{Mon}(C)$ is the category of monoids in $C$), must $C$ be cocartesian?

Note that the forgetful functor must in fact be an isomorphism, because monoid structures are uniquely transportable across isomorphisms in $C$. In particular, every object of $C$ must have exactly one monoid structure, every morphism in $C$ must be a morphism of monoids with respect to the unique structures on the domain and codomain, and there is a "trivial" monoid structure on the unit object $I$ of $C$ with the identity map for its unit, so by preservation of the unit for monoid morphisms, $I$ must be initial.

Knowing that $I$ is initial, one could easily construct "injection" morphisms $i_{X,Y}:X \cong X \otimes I \to X \otimes Y$ and $j_{X,Y}:Y \cong I \otimes Y \to X \otimes Y$.

So, if $\Delta:C \to C \times C$ is the diagonal functor and $\otimes:C \times C \to C$ is the monoidal product functor, then we have natural transformations $\eta:1_{C \times C} \Rightarrow \Delta \circ \otimes$ and $\epsilon:\otimes \circ \Delta \Rightarrow 1_C$ where $\eta_{(X,Y)}$ is $(i_{X,Y}, j_{X,Y})$ and $\epsilon_X$ is the multiplication map of the unique monoid structure on $X$. It remains to show that the triangle identities hold making $\otimes$ left adjoint to $\Delta$ and hence the coproduct. One of them is just the unit axiom for a monoid in $C$, so it suffices to show that $m \circ (i_{X,Y} \otimes j_{X,Y})=1_{X \otimes Y}$ where $m:(X \otimes Y) \otimes (X \otimes Y) \to X \otimes Y$ is the multiplication map of the unique monoid structure on $X \otimes Y$.

So, could $m \circ (i_{X,Y} \otimes j_{X,Y})=1_{X \otimes Y}$ in fact be proven to be true?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348480 seems related: in the opposite category the monoidal structure is cartesian if and only if it symmetric and the counit and comultiplication are monoidal natural transformations. Maybe them being monoidal means they amount to homomorphisms, therefore solving your problem.